# how to fix character maps to undefined unicode error

Tags: python, mysql, csv, unicode

I am attempting to make a CSV of some data from a database in order to move it to the cloud in data warehousing.  However, when I run it, it always quits after 36,599 rows and gives me

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 62: character maps to <undefined>
```

I found that the string causing the issue is 'Rejected-Case No. doesn’t match' and I assume it is a problem with the apostrophe.  I do not know why it is causing this issue and have been unable to find a way around it.  Does anyone know how to solve this?  The code I use is:

```
db = pymysql.connect(host='host', port=3306, user="user", passwd="secret", 
db="db", autocommit=True)
cur = db.cursor()
#cur.execute("call inv1_view_prod.`Email_agg`")

cur.execute("""select fields from table""") 


emails = cur.fetchall()
with open('O:\file\path\to\File_name.csv','w') as fileout:
        writer = csv.writer(fileout)
        writer.writerows(emails)   
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It probably is a \ instead of an apostrophe that is causing the issue.

Comment: @dfundako: `'\x92'` is the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (`’`)in charset cp1252

Answer (score 2):

As you have not shown the code that causes the error, I am just guessing.

The only fact is that this string `'Rejected-Case No. doesn’t match'` contains a `"’"` which is the unicode character U+2019, RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK. In the windows cp1252 code page, this character has indeed the code `0x92`.

It looks like you have *somewhere* a byte string encoded in cp1252 charset that has not been correctly decoded to a unicode string.

What should be done:

There are solutions. Unfortunately, they will depend on the Python version that you are using (2 or 3), and without knowing anything of the code I can only give the generic advices:

- identify the input charset (what the database gives to the Python script)
- identify the output charset (what you want to write in the CSV module)
- use explicit conversions to be able to pass the correct charsets
- optionaly use `error=replace` in the encoding/decoding calls to avoid the UnicodeError exceptions.

---

If you use Python3, I will assume that you have a problem in decoding unicode from the database. The RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK has unicode code U+2019, but in the string given to Python is coded `'\x92'` which is the `cp1252` byte encoding. A quick and dirty fix is to force an encoding/decoding pass to get a correct unicode string. Your code could become:

```
db = pymysql.connect(host='host', port=3306, user="user", passwd="secret", 
db="db", autocommit=True)
cur = db.cursor()
#cur.execute("call inv1_view_prod.`Email_agg`")

cur.execute("""select fields from table""") 

charset = 'cp1252'   # or 'utf8' depending on what you want in the csv file
with open('O:\file\path\to\File_name.csv','w', encoding=charset,
           errors='replace', newline='') as fileout:
        writer = csv.writer(fileout)
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            writer.writerow([field.encode('latin1').decode('cp1252', errors='replace')
                for field in row])
```

The `encode('latin1').decode('cp1252')` is just a trick to fix a Python3 string where characters have the code of a byte encoding. It works because `latin1` encoding is a no-op for all codes under 256.

The `errors=replace` option, ask Python to never raise an UnicodeError exception but instead to replace the offending character with a `'?'` for a byte string or with the official unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER U+FFFD `'�'` for an unicode string.

---

It would probably be cleaner to use the `charset` option of `pymysql.connect`. Unfortunately, I have never used MySQL databases from Python...

Comment: @A.Pearson: is it Python2 or Python3?

Comment: I am usingPython 3

Comment: [_Best practice and debugger_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and [_Python tips_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python)